# Embedding ruby in c++ with args in and return object out

Tags: c++, ruby, embed

I've got a c++ application that I want to be able to embed ruby in.

**I want to**:

1. Construct a ruby object
2. Load a ruby file and call a specific function with that object as an argument
3. Get the return value from that function call in C++ code

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible to pass the object into the ruby script?  If so, can you give a brief example or point me to one?
2. Is it possible to get the return value as an object out of the script into the C++ code?  If so, can you give a brief example or point me to one?

**Additional Reading**

Referencing [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626333/embedding-a-ruby-interpreter-in-a-c-app) in case someone is reading here and wondering how to embed the ruby interpreter in their c++ application.

**[updates]**

1. I found [this discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/147365) about doing exactly what I'm talking about.  So, I would say that the answer is definitively yes, what I'm trying to do is possible.  I'll post an example using [Rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org) a bit later, or on my [blog](http://bitcycle.blogspot.com).

Comment: You can also look onto http://thrift.apache.org/.

Comment: What type is the object returned by the code? What type is the argument?

Comment: The type returned is an object that has a response string and status code.